# Run an event after load a page of a multipage template Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, multipage

I have a multipage template in Jquery Mobile, but I'm trying to run an script (an alert for example) after load a page of this template.

The navigation into pages works with "#page1, #page2..."

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, post your code into the Question and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a solid explanation with code samples explaining what is wrong and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `pagebeforeshow` or `pageload` event for example.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function() {
    alert($.mobile.activePage.attr('id')); //this will get the active page id (like #page1)
});​
```

here is a list of all events http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/